# Error en PDO Insert into

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, insert

estoy haciendo un insert into con PDO usando js, **los datos se guardan bien en la base de datos** pero no sé porque no me entra a function succes() y no me muestra el mensaje. Cuando hago un **print_r($insert->errorInfo());** me muestra **Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )**. Lo revisé y he buscado documentacion y no encuentro el error.

Lo que quiero es que si se está guardando el base de datos me muestre el mensaje de "El registro ha sido guardado correctamente."

```
          if (isset($_POST['Nombre'])) 
          {
             include_once('conexion.php');
            try {

                  $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                  $conexion = DB::conectar();
                 
                  $insert = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO Solicitud  (NombreEmpresa, Nombre, Apellido, Email, Telefono, SitioWeb, TipoPlan, PaisID, FechaSolicitud, FechaProcesandoDemo, Activo) VALUES ( :NombreEmpresa, :Nombre, :Apellido, :Email, :Telefono, :SitioWeb, :TipoPlan, :PaisID,  :FechaSolicitud, :FechaProcesandoDemo, :Activo  )");

                  $insert->bindValue('NombreEmpresa',$_POST['NombreEmpresa']);
                  $insert->bindValue('Nombre',$_POST['Nombre']);
                  $insert->bindValue('Apellido',$_POST['Apellido']);
                  $insert->bindValue('Email',$_POST['Email']);
                  $insert->bindValue('Telefono',$_POST['Telefono']);
                  $insert->bindValue('SitioWeb',$_POST['SitioWeb']);
                  $insert->bindValue('TipoPlan',$_POST['TipoPlan']);
                  $insert->bindValue('PaisID',$_POST['PaisID']);
                  $insert->bindValue('FechaSolicitud',$now);
                  $insert->bindValue('FechaProcesandoDemo','0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                  $insert->bindValue('Activo',1);
                  $insert->execute();
                  print_r($insert->errorInfo());
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
               echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }else{}
```

y este es el código js:

```
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#btnSolicitar', function (event){
       var msj = jQuery('#msj');
    
        var btnself = jQuery('#btnSolicitar');
        var dataForm = jQuery('#frmSolicitud').serialize();
            $.ajax({
              url: '/solicitar.php',
              cache: false,
              type: 'POST',
              data: dataForm,
              dataType: 'json',
              beforeSend: function ()
              {
                  btnself.prop('disabled', true);
                  wrapperContent(msj,'<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Por favor espere, procesando datos.</div>');
                  hiddenTimeLayer(msj, 5000); 
                  console.log("error1");
              },
              success: function() {
                 // $("#msj").html('Correcto');
                 wrapperContent(msj,'<div class="alert alert-success">El registro ha sido guardado correctamente.</div>');
                 hiddenTimeLayer(msj, 5000); 
                  console.log("error2");
              },
              error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError)
              {
                wrapperContent(msj,'<div class="alert alert-danger">AJAX: Ocurrió un problema (<strong>' + thrownError + ')</strong> de comunicación al solicitar su petición, por favor intente nuevamente, sí el problema persiste contacte con el Administrador.</div><div class="divider15"></div>');
                  btnself.removeProp('disabled',true);
                  console.log("error3");
              }               
          });
    
});
```

Por favor, si encuentran algún error o alguna idea comentarla. Estaré pendiente. No sé si sea error de codigo o el insert no lo estoy haciendo bien.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu código PHP, se ejecuta el insert, pero solo imprimes si hay error.

Tendrías que obtener el número de filas afectadas:

```
print_r($insert->rowCount());
```

Y en el success compruebas las filas afectadas:

```
success: function(respuesta) {
   if(respuesta>0){                
      wrapperContent(msj,'<div class="alert alert-success">El registro ha sido guardado correctamente.</div>');
      hiddenTimeLayer(msj, 5000); 
   }
},
```

Comment: Kirito, asuna ha shinda :v.

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente me funciono de esta manera

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas estas diciendole a `ajax` que lo que quieres que te devuelva `PHP` sea en forma de `JSON`:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

por lo tanto lo que hara `$.ajax` de `jQuery` es esperar a una respuesta y si no hay errores intentar parsear la respuesta a un `json`, el error seguro debe ser que `ajax` no esta pudiendo parsear la respuesta a un `json` porque simplemente lo que devuelves desde el backend es ya sea algo que **NO** es un `json` o simplemente no devuelves nada.

Para solucionarlo hay dos formas, la primera es simplemente quitar `dataType` de `ajax` para no esperar un json directamente.

La segunda es si regresar un `json` desde el backend, quedando asi:

```
<?php

   $message;

   if (isset($_POST['Nombre'])) 
   {
      ...
      ...
      ...
      $hayError = $insert->execute();
      if(!$hayError){
         $message = json_encode(["state" => "success", "msg" => "inserted successfully!"]);
      }else{
         $message = json_encode(["state" => "failed", "msg" => "something went wrong!"]);
      }

   }else{
      $message = json_encode(["state" => "failed", "msg" => "Some data was not provided! (Name)"]);
   }

   //Al final de todo retornarias la respuesta:
   echo $message;

?>
```

De esta manera `ajax` entraria al success.

Ah porcierto, siendo que le estas diciendo a `ajax` que use como `dataType json`, creo que `success` espera como minimo un parametro, pero esto no se si realmente sea opcional, por si las moscas agregale un parametro que se llame de cualquier forma:

```
success: function(data) {

}
```

Y por si depronto requieres la respuesta traida por `ajax`, la podras usar directamente en la funcion del `success` sin problemas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, también me funciono de esta manera. Y si era porque no estoy retornando un json. Lo único que cuando me iba a Network > response me mostraba el mensaje de Failed.